# How can I find the cause of this program failure

Tags: c

I am attempting to get a string literal printed but there seems to be some problem and it doesn't give any output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char *device_name = "mychardev";
    void test_pointer(device_name);
    return 0;
}

void test_pointer(char *p)
{
    while(*p!= NULL);
    { 
        printf("%s",*p);
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the compiler warnings?

Comment: Look at how you're calling `printf`, then look at how you're calling `test_pointer`.  Notice a difference?

Comment: The eternal `while(*p!= NULL);` loop needs some attention. When do you think that loop will end? It should be `while(*p != '\0')` without the semi-colon.

Comment: The argument for `%s` must be a null-terminated string. `*p` is a single character, not a string.

Comment: In `*p!= NULL` you are comparing a chracter with a pointer. And in `printf("%s",*p);` you provide a character where a pointer is needed.

Comment: Use `%c` to print a single character.

Comment: Or use `putchar(*p);`

Comment: You never actually call the defective function – only provided a *declaration*. You need `void test_pointer(char *p);` above main, and change the thing in main to `test_pointer(device_name);`

Comment: Why do you think your editor indented the lines after the `while` they way it did (as opposed to way they are now)?

Comment: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 4):

In no particular order.

- While loop: the trailing semicolon means that your while loop isd *just* `while(*p!= NULL);`. If `*p` starts out equal to `NULL` the loop never runs. If it isn't, `p` never gets updated, so the loop never *stops*.
- The condition the while loop is testing compares a `char` value with `NULL` which is a larger integer type. To avoid possible problems, compare with the null character itself: `while (*p != '\0')`
- Your *call* of `test_pointer` in `main` doesn't need the `void`. Just `test_pointer(device_name);` As it stands, this looks like a declaration of a function inside `main`, but without a type for `device_name`.
- Your call to `printf` in `test_pointer` is using the wrongh format specifier. You're dereferencing `p`, which gives you a `char` value, so use `%c` rather than `%s`. Passing a char when a string is expected yields undefined behavior.
- You have not forward declared `test_pointer` before calling it in `main`.

Compiling your program with gcc and `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` yields the following warnings/errors. All of these would be informative and help you identify these issues. I strongly suggest you turn warnings on in your compiler.

When you gets warnings/errors, get into the habit of fixing the first one, then recompiling. Often one issue creates others, and one fix clears up multiple problems.

```
test3.c: In function ‘main’:
test3.c:6:5: error: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [-Werror]
     void test_pointer(device_name);
     ^~~~
test3.c:5:11: error: unused variable ‘device_name’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     char *device_name = "mychardev";
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
test3.c: In function ‘test_pointer’:
test3.c:12:13: error: comparison between pointer and integer [-Werror]
     while(*p!= NULL);
             ^~
test3.c:12:5: error: this ‘while’ clause does not guard... [-Werror=misleading-indentation]
     while(*p!= NULL);
     ^~~~~
test3.c:13:5: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘while’
     {
     ^
test3.c:14:18: error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Werror=format=]
         printf("%s",*p);
                 ~^  ~~
                 %d
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: `while(*p!= NULL)` is incorrect as the warning, should be `while(*p!= '\0')`

Comment: @WeatherVane More egregious is that `while(*p!= NULL);` should be `while(*p!= NULL)` There was a time [about 10 years ago] where only `clang` warned about this by default because `-Wall` included `-Wempty-body` but `gcc` didn't. I spent a week tracking down such a bug in my own code (of a few thousand lines). In desperation, thinking `gcc` had a code generation error, I rebuild with `clang` and it flagged it immediately. IIRC, back then, `gcc` needed `-Wextra` to warn about this. lesson learned [mine].

Comment: @CraigEstey that was covered in this answer and in comments too, but an exhaustive list of faults should mention comparing integer with pointer – the compiler warns. But apparently nobody considers it important.

Comment: "NULL which is a larger integer type" It is not guaranteed to be an integer type at all and most often it isn't.